# Pass Data via Segue to UITabBarController in another Storyboard pushed onto the Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am trying to push some data to a `ViewController` in another Storyboard, but I am having trouble getting the order correct.

I have `UITableView` that has a list of items, upon selecting a row, I want to pass a key to the `ViewController` that is on another Storyboard embedded in a `UITabBarContoller` that has been pushed to the navigation stack.

I can transition back and forth with no issues, the problem is getting the data over to the view controller.

**My table view code in my Main Storyboard**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_details", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("Pepare for segue: \(String(describing: segue.identifier))")

    if let barViewControllers = segue.destination as? UITabBarController ,
        let nav = barViewControllers.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController,
        let destinationVC = nav.topViewController as? DetailsTabViewController {
        let vehicle = tableData[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row] as! JSON
        //THIS NEVER FIRES
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\nPrepare call key: \(vehicle["CallKey"])\n\n\n\n\n")
        destinationVC.callKey =  vehicle["CallKey"].stringValue
    }
}
```

I have switched the `if let`'s barViewControllers and navigation controllers trying to get the correct View controller, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is a ScreenShot of the Main Storyboard's `UITableView`

[image]

The **DetailsTabViewController** code

```
class DetailsTabViewController: UITabBarController {
    public var callKey : String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("\n\n\n\n\n Details for callKey: \(callKey) \n\n\n\n\n")
        title = callKey;
    }
}
```

And its matching Storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's not as complicated as I thought. The segue destination is the DetailsTabViewController. Just cast to that instead of UITabBarController (since my custom class is already of type `UITabBarController`).

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let barViewControllers = segue.destination as? DetailsTabViewController {
               //Do your data pass / setup here

    }
}
```